# Can I upgrade obsolete units, and if so, how?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Is it possible to upgrade my existing infantry, or must I disband the old units and build new ones?

I purchased the next military technology level which opened up Azab Infantry and made Yaya Infantry obsolete. It prompted me to choose the new unit type, but I cannot find a way to upgrade my existing infantry.

I'm in the middle of a Peasant War (endless uprisings) and have no manpower left. Will disbanding units put the remaining men back into the manpower pool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you change your default unit type (e.g. because of an upgrade to a better unit), all your troops will automatically "evolve" into that new unit type. There are no further actions you have to do about that. This will happen **always** when you change a unit type.

Keep in mind however that changing a unit type will give all troops that contain the affected existing units a severe drop in morale. This is due to the short-time chaos that comes with reorganizing a regiment.

For this reason, changing the unit type in the middle of a war can be a bad idea, depending on the situation of course.

Comment: This only applies to land units. The only way to upgrade ships is to build new ones and scuttle the old.

Comment: Obviously, because there is no way to change the ship type manually. Still - good addition.

Comment: It also only appears to work for "native" units, not mercenaries. (If there's a way other than disband/rebuild to upgrade mercenaries, I'd love to know).

Comment: @joseph_morris, no, there is no way of upgrading mercenary stacks apart from what you state: disbandment & hire